# get refund transaction data with product metadata woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to get refunded transaction data with all details of the product like product id and how much quantity refunded.

Can I get all details in array format?

Answer (score 1):

First of all +1 for your question. From `WooCommerce 2.2` onwards, WooCommerce directly allows refunds if your payment gateway allows. Refunding can be done in 2 ways: Automatically via Payment Gateway or Manually. Please refer the page: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-refunds/ for more information. If you want to get the refund details please use the methods listed in this page: http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html.

Comment: Hey @Asok thanks for help but I want to get refund data with this : order_id , product ID and quantity. can you help me to get this?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a proper way to do this using built in WooCommerce classes (reports by day is...close). I dug through queries used by WooCommerce to pull report data and came up with the following to get refunded order items:

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;

    // TODO: time zones, better ranges, etc.

    $date_start = new DateTime('-7 days');
    $date_end   = new DateTime('now');

    $sql_reports_refunded = <<<SQL

          SELECT
            product_id.meta_value        AS product_id,
            variation_id.meta_value      AS variation_id,
            order_items.order_item_name  AS product_name,
            product_sku.meta_value       AS product_SKU,
            variation_sku.meta_value     AS variation_SKU,
            SUM(quantity.meta_value)     AS quantity

          FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS posts

          LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items     AS order_items    ON posts.ID = order_items.order_id
          LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta  AS quantity       ON order_items.order_item_id = quantity.order_item_id      AND quantity.meta_key      = '_qty'
          LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta  AS variation_id   ON order_items.order_item_id = variation_id.order_item_id  AND variation_id.meta_key  = '_variation_id'
          LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta  AS product_id     ON order_items.order_item_id = product_id.order_item_id    AND product_id.meta_key    = '_product_id'
          LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta                    AS product_sku    ON product_id.meta_value     = product_sku.post_id         AND product_sku.meta_key   = '_sku'
          LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta                    AS variation_sku  ON variation_id.meta_value   = variation_sku.post_id       AND variation_sku.meta_key = '_sku'

          WHERE posts.post_status IN ('wc-completed', 'wc-refunded')
            AND posts.post_type IN ('shop_order_refund')
            AND posts.post_date >= '{$date_start->format('Y-m-d')}'
            AND posts.post_date <  '{$date_end->format('Y-m-d')}'
            AND order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item'
            AND order_items.order_id IS NOT NULL

          GROUP BY product_id, variation_id
          ORDER BY quantity DESC, product_name ASC

    SQL;

    return $wpdb->get_results($sql_reports_refunded);
?>
```

It's very close to what WC is using to grab data for various reports. As I write this I would suggest that if you need custom reporting from WooCommerce you will likely have to do things yourself via custom queries or `get_order_report_data` in `WC_Admin_Report`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if you compare these results to the counts from WooCommerce things might be off. They add an extra day to the provided end date when they check things like totals.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is almost a couple years old, but it's the only discussion I found regarding obtaining refund data. Anoop's answer is correct, but to better clarify, the refund methods from WC_Order should return what's neededL https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html

Example: I'm building a list of "attendees" to an event-style product. The number of attendees looks at purchased orders' quantities of that product/event. Refunding by way of quantity doesn't actually adjust the order's quantity, but rather the quantity of items refunded are stored here:

```
WC_Order()->get_item_count_refunded();
```

General refund details can be obtained with:

```
WC_Order()->get_refunds();
```